# Is it possible to typecast a const variable?

Tags: c

As we all know that we can't change or modified a constant variable in C. But when I did typecasting on a constant variable, its value got changed. I mean, it shouldn't happen.

Is this expected behavior?

```
EDIT:

main()
{
  int const i=1;
  printf("%d",(float)i);
}
```

output is 0

Comment: Can you give an example of what you tried?

Comment: why should the value of a volatile not have changed?

Comment: You print the integer as a float! That will definitely show the wrong value.

Comment: ok let me print integer as integer .

Comment: "o/p is 0" -- What does this mean?

Comment: output comes out to be 0

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's expected. A type cast doesn't change the variable, it reinterprets the value in memory as a different type.

Answer (score 4):

```
printf("%f",i);
```

will interpret i as a float. If you look in memory, you will see that i doesn't change, but rather the memory it's located at is reinterpreted:

```
  int const i=1;
     0x0012FF60  01 00 00 00 //memory location of i
  float k;
  k=(float)i; 
     0x0012FF60  01 00 00 00 //i still the same
  printf("%f",i);
```

Answer (score 3):

A cast doesn't "cast a variable".

A cast applies to an expression, that is first your value is evaluated and then it is converted to the other type.

(Also, the rest of your code is, well, improvable. Please have a look into the allowed prototypes for `main` and always put a `\n` at the end of a `printf`.)

Answer (score 0):

value is not going to change but you are doing misunderstanding in prinf statement

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
  int const i=1;
  float k;
  k=(float)i; 
  printf("in decimal %d\n",i);
  printf("in float %f \n",(float)i);
  printf("k is %f \n",k);
  return 0;
}
```

see its output is

```
in decimal 1
in float 1.000000 
k is 1.000000
```

see http://codepad.org/A2FWkncK

**your mistake**

```
 k=(float)i;
```

**this statement wil not change the value of i but it will cast the value of i in float and then assign to k**

```
 printf("%f",i);
```

here you are printing int value by %f so it will give you wrong value

Answer (score 0):

You code does not change the value of the `const` variable `i`.  It converts that value to a `float` and stores the result in `k`, but leaves `i` unmolested.

Your `printf()` call has undefined behaviour, because you have used the `%f` format specifier with an `int` argument (when it requires a `double`).  The reason that this is manifesting as `1.000000` is likely because your architecture's calling convention passes floating point values in a different location to scalar values, and that floating point location happens to still contain the value of `k` from the prior conversion.